# Bottom-up and memorization of the Fibonacci

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming, memoization

I'm made a memorization version of the Fibonacci function (code commented out). Now I want to make a bottom-up and memorization version of the same function. However, my solution seem to be out of the range for really large numbers.

```
class Solution
{
public:
//Function to count number of ways to reach the nth stair.
    
    int fib(int n)
    {   
        // int memo[n + 1];
        
        // for(int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++) {
        //     memo[i] = -1;
        // }
        
        // if(memo[n] == -1) {
        //     if(n <= 2) {
        //         memo[n] = 1;
        //     } else {
        //         memo[n] = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
        //     }
        // }
        
        // return memo[n]; 
        int memo[n + 1];
        
        memo[0] = 1;
        memo[1] = 1;
        memo[2] = 1;
        
        for(int i = 3; i < n + 1; i++) {
            memo[i] = memo[i - 1] + memo[i - 2];
        }
        return memo[n];
    }

    // Returns number of ways to
    // reach s'th stair
    int countWays(int s)
    {
        int memo[s + 1];
        return fib(s + 1);
    }
};
```

example input:

```
Input:
84

Its Correct output is:
93254120

And Your Code's output is:
-1289228135
```

Comment: Time to learn how to use a *debugger* to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. That's the usual way to help figure out these kind of problems.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? That's the first step. Then, if there is something you don't understand, you should get back here with details.

Comment: By the way, `int memo[n+1];` defines `memo` as a [variable-length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) and those doesn't really exist in C++. Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: As for the "large values" part, `93254120` isn't a very large value. It should fit very well into the range of a 32-bit signed integer (which `int` usually is). You could always use `uint64_t` to increase range to an unsigned 64-bit type which should be able to handle much more than the plus/minus 2 billion plain `int` can handle.

Comment: `93254120` is not the correct result. In fact it's way of. `F(84) > pow(1.6, 84) / sqrt(5) > 6e13` which is out of the range of 32 bit integral values btw. (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `uint64_t` instead of `int` to cover wider range of numbers (up to term number 93 which is 12200160415121876738) and avoid this overflow problem, also correct that `memo[0] = 0;` not `1`. Finally, the term number 84 is 160500643816367088 not 93254120.

The prober code for the first method should be like this:

```
uint64_t fib(int n)
{
    if (n < 2)
        return n;
    else
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}
```

This code will take long time for later terms.

For the second method:

```
uint64_t fib(int n)
{
    uint64_t *memo = new uint64_t[n + 1];
    memo[0] = 0;
    memo[1] = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        memo[i] = memo[i - 1] + memo[i - 2];
    return memo[n];
}
```

This one is much more efficient and faster.

Comment: A looped version does not need an `n` size array: `memo[n+1]`.   With a few other changes, `memo[3]` will do.